# What was Newman's first name?

Tags: character, seinfeld

Was Newman's first name ever mentioned anywhere in *Seinfeld*? I don't recall anybody calling him by any other name (except "Norman" by his girlfriend which was a mistake because she didn't know the name).

Or was the name always kept a mystery? (Whatever the reason)

Edit: I have assumed that Newman is the last name. But sanpaco says in the comment that Newman might as well be the first name. Well we never know. :-) In that case you can assume I am asking for his last name.

[image]

Comment: Who says "Newman" isn't his first name?

Comment: @sanpaco +1 Good point. Question edited. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was never mentioned in any episode, probably intentionally. The one episode where a woman yells "Goodbye, Norman" was a case of the actress misreading the script.

[Seinfeld wikia](http://seinfeld.wikia.com/wiki/Newman)

Comment: Possible add to your answer, I would say, at least from what I'm reading, not only is his first name "not mentioned", he simply doesn't have a "first name".  In "The Package"(S8, E5), Newman's business card is shown; it simply reads "NEWMAN".

Comment: @New-To-IT - That would seem like a very Larry David/Jerry Seinfeld intentional twist.